# filtered colimit of $Hom_{A_i}(M_0\otimes_{A_0} A_i, N_0\otimes_{A_0} A_i)$

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $I$ be a small [filtered category](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filtered_category).
Let $F\colon I \rightarrow \textbf{CRng}$ be a functor, where $\textbf{CRng}$ is the category of commutative rings.
We write $A_i = F(i)$ for $i \in I$,
$A =$ colim $A_i$.
Suppose $I$ has an initial object $0$.
Let $M_0, N_0$ be $A_0$-modules.
Suppose $M_0$ is of finite presentation.
Then colim $\textrm{Hom}_{A_i}(M_0\otimes_{A_0} A_i, N_0\otimes_{A_0} A_i)$ is canonically isomorphic to 
$\textrm{Hom}_{A}(M_0\otimes_{A_0} A, N_0\otimes_{A_0} A)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The universal property of scalar extension says
$$\textrm{Hom}_{A_i}(M_0 \otimes_{A_0} A_i, N_0 \otimes_{A_0} A_i) \cong \textrm{Hom}_{A_0} (M_0, N_0 \otimes_{A_0} A_i)$$
naturally, so
$$\varinjlim \textrm{Hom}_{A_i}(M_0 \otimes_{A_0} A_i, N_0 \otimes_{A_0} A_i) \cong \varinjlim \textrm{Hom}_{A_0} (M_0, N_0 \otimes_{A_0} A_i) \cong \textrm{Hom}_{A_0} (M_0, \varinjlim  N_0 \otimes_{A_0} A_i)$$
where in the last step we have used the fact that $M_0$ is of finite presentation; and since $N_0 \otimes_{A_0} (-)$ is a left adjoint,
$$\varinjlim  N_0 \otimes_{A_0} A_i \cong N_0 \otimes_{A_0} \varinjlim A_i \cong N_0 \otimes_{A_0} A$$
and therefore
$$\varinjlim \textrm{Hom}_{A_i}(M_0 \otimes_{A_0} A_i, N_0 \otimes_{A_0} A_i) \cong \textrm{Hom}_{A_0}(M_0, N_0 \otimes_{A_0} A) \cong \textrm{Hom}_A(M_0 \otimes_{A_0} A, N_0 \otimes_{A_0} A)$$
as claimed.

Comment: Could you explain how the last step of the second equation is proved by using the assumption that $M_0$ is of finite presentation?

Comment: $\textrm{Hom}_{A_0}(M_0, -)$ preserves filtered colimits if (and only if) $M_0$ is a finitely-presented $A_0$-module.

Comment: A proof, please?

Comment: The proof I posted [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265916/on-colim-hom-a-algb-c-i) covers this.